# Xamarin Hot Reload not failed to initialize

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hot-reload

After the last updates of Visual Studio version 16.9.x and update to Xamarin.Forms 5.0 Hot Reload not working.

This is the Output i get when starting the application:

```
Hot Reload IDE Extension Loaded
(FinansovoPregledi.Android) XAML Hot Reload is using 'changes only' mode
XAML Hot Reload initializing...
WARN: (FinansovoPregledi.Android) Unknown Breakpoint Hit: Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives( typeName_ptr, int typeName_len,  jniClass,  methods_ptr, int methods_len)
ERROR: Caught exception in AgentStatusChangedHandler at 268: Xamarin.HotReload.EvaluatorException: Failed to Inject Assembly ---> Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.EvaluatorException: Method `Load' not found in type `System.Reflection.Assembly'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.OverloadResolveMulti(SoftEvaluationContext ctx, TypeMirror type, String methodName, ArgumentType[] genericTypeArgs, TypeMirror returnType, ArgumentType[] argTypes, List`1 candidates, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean tryCasting) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2619
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.OverloadResolveMulti(SoftEvaluationContext ctx, TypeMirror type, String methodName, ArgumentType[] genericTypeArgs, TypeMirror returnType, ArgumentType[] argTypes, Boolean allowInstance, Boolean allowStatic, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean tryCasting) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2511
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.RuntimeInvoke(EvaluationContext ctx, Object targetType, Object target, String methodName, Object[] genericTypeArgs, Object[] argTypes, Object[] argValues, Boolean enableOutArgs, Object[]& outArgs) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2304
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.RuntimeInvoke(EvaluationContext ctx, Object targetType, Object target, String methodName, Object[] genericTypeArgs, Object[] argTypes, Object[] argValues) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2281
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadSharedBridge.InjectAndLoadAssembly(IProject project, SoftEvaluationContext context, String assemblyPath) in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadSharedBridge.cs:line 359
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadSharedBridge.InjectAndLoadAssembly(IProject project, SoftEvaluationContext context, String assemblyPath) in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadSharedBridge.cs:line 374
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<InitializeAgent>d__47.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 140
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<<Debugger_TargetHitBreakpoint>b__50_0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 242
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadSharedBridge.InjectAndLoadAssembly(IProject project, SoftEvaluationContext context, String assemblyPath) in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadSharedBridge.cs:line 374
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<InitializeAgent>d__47.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 140
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<<Debugger_TargetHitBreakpoint>b__50_0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 242
XAML Hot Reload encountered a problem and failed to start. Use Help -> Report a Problem if the issues persists.
Stopping All Hot Reload sessions due to Failed ...
(FinansovoPregledi.Android) Stopping a Hot Reload session due to Failed ...
Stopped Hot Reload session.
ERROR: (FinansovoPregledi.Android) Caught exception in Debugger_TargetHitBreakpoint at 246: Xamarin.HotReload.EvaluatorException: Failed to Inject Assembly ---> Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.EvaluatorException: Method `Load' not found in type `System.Reflection.Assembly'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.OverloadResolveMulti(SoftEvaluationContext ctx, TypeMirror type, String methodName, ArgumentType[] genericTypeArgs, TypeMirror returnType, ArgumentType[] argTypes, List`1 candidates, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean tryCasting) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2619
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.OverloadResolveMulti(SoftEvaluationContext ctx, TypeMirror type, String methodName, ArgumentType[] genericTypeArgs, TypeMirror returnType, ArgumentType[] argTypes, Boolean allowInstance, Boolean allowStatic, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean tryCasting) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2511
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.RuntimeInvoke(EvaluationContext ctx, Object targetType, Object target, String methodName, Object[] genericTypeArgs, Object[] argTypes, Object[] argValues, Boolean enableOutArgs, Object[]& outArgs) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2304
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.RuntimeInvoke(EvaluationContext ctx, Object targetType, Object target, String methodName, Object[] genericTypeArgs, Object[] argTypes, Object[] argValues) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2281
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadSharedBridge.InjectAndLoadAssembly(IProject project, SoftEvaluationContext context, String assemblyPath) in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadSharedBridge.cs:line 359
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadSharedBridge.InjectAndLoadAssembly(IProject project, SoftEvaluationContext context, String assemblyPath) in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadSharedBridge.cs:line 374
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<InitializeAgent>d__47.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 140
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<<Debugger_TargetHitBreakpoint>b__50_0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 242
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadSharedBridge.InjectAndLoadAssembly(IProject project, SoftEvaluationContext context, String assemblyPath) in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadSharedBridge.cs:line 374
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<InitializeAgent>d__47.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 140
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadBridge.<<Debugger_TargetHitBreakpoint>b__50_0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Bridge\HotReloadBridge.cs:line 242
```

Does anyone have a same problem? I tried everything for all platforms, also selecting to refresh the whole page but nothing fixed my problem. It's so hard without Hot Reload.

Comment: Since 16.9.3 I had to change my settings Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Hot Reload and set the mode from Changes only to Full page to get it working again.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer i tried that not working

Comment: @Rajzer   In your Android and iOS build settings, check that the Linker is set to "Don't Link" or "Link None".

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT mark as answer

Comment: @Rajzer Glad to help you, I have post one reply for your thread now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Android and iOS build settings, check that the Linker is set to "Don't Link" or "Link None".
More detailed info about XAML Hot Reload for Xamarin.Forms, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload

Comment: Thier is no dont link settings ! Wording has changed i wish msfs would update their fricking docs