# Have a simple .net Maui app and the hot reload for android in VS keeps failing to initialize

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui, hot-reload

I have a simple Todo app that I am working on through a tutorial. I have been using the Windows Machine hot reload fine. But I added in some swipe controls so I wanted to test it in the android emulator. I have the newest version of VS and the android emulator but I receive the below exception:

**[9:19:46 PM]  Caught exception in AgentStatusChangedHandler at 317: Xamarin.HotReload.DebuggerTimeoutException: Failed to Inject Assembly**

This is driving me crazy! I can't figure out what is wrong. Please any info would be most helpful.

Comment: you have to looks at the AgentStatusChangedHandler at 317 :) or share that with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Debug** > **Options** > **XAML Hot Reload** from the Visual Studio menu bar to see whether the relevant platform is checked.

For more options and details, you can refer to this: [XAML Hot Reload for .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin).

In addition, I searched relevant case about it. You can take a look at this case: [Xamarin Hot Reload not failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089517/xamarin-hot-reload-not-failed-to-initialize). Wish it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my issue was. Hopefully this helps someone else. I had to get the **SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl** NuGet package. MS says you need this along with **sqlite-net-pcl** to work with Android.